# Types of knot invariants

Tags: knot-theory

Knot invariants seem to roughly be either numbers (that is, an amount of something ), polynomials, matrices, or groups. Are there any other invariants that have been studied that are not of this form?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sure. For example,

- [Khovanov homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khovanov_homology) is a bigraded abelian group,
- the [knot quandle](http://www.thehcmr.org/issue1_2/knot_quandle.pdf) is a [quandle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quandle),
- the [Kontsevich integral](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kontsevich+integral) is an element of the algebra of chord diagrams.